# Selecting only some values from dictionaries in list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have such list with dictionaries:

```
one_list = [{'true black': ['AA1', ['BB']]}, {'white': ['AA2', ['CC1', 'CC2']]}]
```

i need to produce next one:

```
list = ['AA1', 'BB', 'CC1', 'CC2']
```

So I need to take [0] element of 'true black' , then all elements from [1] element of 'true black' and [1] of all others dictionaries

```
                for i in one_list:
                    if 'true_black' in i.keys():
                        for v in i.values():
                            container.append(v[0])
                            for v1 in v[1]:
                                pic_container.append(v1)
```

But I`m getting

```
 >>> ['AA1', 'AA2', 'BB', 'CC1', 'CC2']
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how your given code can add `'CC1'` and `'CC2'` to your resulting list. Your code only does something if `'true_black'` is in the dictionary keys, and nothing otherwise.

Comment: so a list of single key dicts?

Comment: @GregHewgill i need to do it only for specific colors which are passing in arguments

Comment: OP: you have a number of workable solutions, but I've gotta be the stick in the mud that asks WHY? Why are you constructing your data structure like this? What do these things mean? Wouldn't it be better to make a `Color` class and make a list of objects, rather than a list of single-element dictionaries?

Comment: @AdamSmith thanx Adam, I know, but requirement is not to use classes

Comment: @user3761151 how about a `collections.namedtuple` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming I got what you where asking for (code for Python 3.x, specifically 3.4):

```
lead_color_name = 'true black'

one_list = [{'true black': ['AA1', ['BB']]}, {'white': ['AA2', ['CC1', 'CC2']]}]

non_lead_colors = [x for x in one_list if lead_color_name not in x]

lead_color = [x for x in one_list if lead_color_name in x][0][lead_color_name]

end_list = []
end_list.append(lead_color[0])
end_list.extend(lead_color[1])
for x in non_lead_colors:
    end_list.extend(list(x.values())[0][1])
print(end_list)
```

end_list gives me (which is what you said you wanted):

```
['AA1', 'BB', 'CC1', 'CC2']
```

**Edit:** I updated the code to account for a "lead" color, in this case your lead color is "true black". This way if you need a different color instead of true black to start, you can easily change the key.

For example, if you wanted your lead color to be white instead of true black, the result would be

```
['AA2', 'CC1', 'CC2', 'BB']
```

If you add more colors to the one_list with the same format as the other colors you will get their internal lists such as 'BB' or ('CC1 and 'CC2') appended to the output list as you requested.

So, per your comment if one_list was as follows:

```
one_list = [{'true black': ['AA1', ['BB']]}, {'white': ['AA2', ['CC1', 'CC2']]}, {'blue': ['AA3', ['DD1', 'DD2']]}]
```

end_list would be:

```
['AA1', 'BB', 'CC1', 'CC2', 'DD1', 'DD2']
```

Comment: will it work if there shell be some other colors in one_list?

Comment: @user3761151 if you add other colors other than white with the same form. It should. I added >> , {'blue': ['AA3', ['DD1', 'DD2']]} << to the one_list and the resulting end_list is >> ['AA1', 'BB', 'CC1', 'CC2', 'DD1', 'DD2'] <<. So, assuming the other dictionaries hold the same format, the end_list will accumulate the colors in that manner.

Comment: why are you making a list out of a list?

Comment: @padraic I assume you are asking about the non_lead_colors list? It is simply a list of dictionary references without whatever lead color is chosen. I suppose I should have made a generator instead of a list or did a >> if lead_color_name not in x << check in the loop (and looped over one_list instead) at the bottom and that would have been fine I guess.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
one_list = [{'true black': ['AA1', ['BB']]}, {'white': ['AA2', ['CC1', 'CC2']]}]

ret_list = []

for i in one_list:
    if i.get("true black"):
        for j in list(i.values())[0]:
            if isinstance(j, list):
            ret_list += j
        else:
            ret_list.append(j)

    else:
        ret_list += i.popitem()[1][1]

print(ret_list)
```

Comment: what if they are not all strings and why not use `ret_list = []`?

Comment: it's only strings and list in dictionary values, may be this version is more effective。 well, i do some test found that's a bad habit, `list()` spend more time than `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do it:

```
one_list = [{'true black': ['AA1', ['BB']]}, {'white': ['AA2', ['CC1', 'CC2']]}]

color = 'true black'
first = one_list[0][color]
new_list = [first[0], first[1][0]]
gen = (g for g in one_list if color not in g.keys())
for g in gen:
    for l in g.values():
        for n in l[1]:
            new_list.append(n)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['AA1', 'BB', 'CC1', 'CC2']
```